# How to replace legacy datatypes in application working via OLEDB?

Tags: sql-server, oledb

Microsoft wrote:

> The TEXT, NTEXT, and IMAGE data types will be removed in a future
>   version of SQL Server. Avoid using them in new development work, and
>   plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use the
>   varchar(max), nvarchar(max), and varbinary(max) data types instead.

I can replace these types in tables, SPs, but should I modify C++ client code? Or it can work unmodified with the new types?

Comment: If the app code simply uses the values as large value types, no code changes are likely needed. Changes are required if it uses `TEXTPTR`, `READTEXT`, `WRITETEXT`, etc.

Comment: Great! Thnx Dan. Create an answer and I will mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app code simply uses the column values as large value types, no code changes are likely needed. Changes are required if the code uses `TEXTPTR`, `READTEXT`, `WRITETEXT`, etc. (directly or via API method) as these T-SQL elements only operate on the legacy types.